# Why would my serializer be returning the Objects ID instead of the object itself?

Tags: django-rest-framework

I'm trying to create an object from a post request and I'm using a serializer. My understanding was that the DRF serializers.ModelSerialzer would get the object.

But my serializer is getting the id for users and league instead of the objects themselves. I'm getting around it by using the ID to get the object I actually need, but I feel like I'm missing something. Shouldn't my serializer do this automatically?

View:

```
class AddCompetitorToLeague(generics.CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = CompetitorSerializer

    def post(self, request):
        serializers = CompetitorSerializer(data=request.data, context={'request': request})

        if serializers.is_valid():
            userId = serializers.data.get('user')
            leagueId = serializers.data.get('league')

            user = User.objects.get(id=userId)
            league = League.objects.get(id=leagueId)

            comp = Competitor(user=user, league=league)
            comp.save()

            return Response(CompetitorSerializer(comp).data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        print('---------------')
        print(serializers.errors)
```

Serializer Code:

```
class CompetitorSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Competitor
        fields = ('user', 'league',)
```

Model Code:

```
class Competitor(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    league = models.ForeignKey(League, on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True)

    pointsFromPos = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    pointsFromPick = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def total_points(self):
        return self.pointsFromPos + self.pointsFromPick
```

Comment: You need [nested serializers](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships)

Comment: can I have a look at your request data?

Comment: {
    "user": "93839c70-9e9b-4ae5-8a00-bab84743f0ca",
    "league": 3
}


This is the issue I believe, I'm using a generics.CreateAPIView to send the request atm. Will the values sent change when I hook this up to the frontend?

Comment: you can achiev this by using `SerializerMethodField`  https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield

Comment: Or you should nest the objects that you want to serialize